# Rent a car in Poland without a credit card

Tags: car-rentals, payment-cards, poland

This summer I tried to rent a car in Warsaw without a credit card. It wasn't an easy task and it took my hours of talking until I could convince them that it is possible. However, I had to pay the whole bail money in cash.

For the next time, I would like to ensure if there is a company in Poland that does not require a credit card for renting a car.

Last time I used [Budget](http://www.budget.com/budgetWeb/home/home.ex).

Comment: I think that this is a usual procedure for car rental companies, no? They need to be able to recover their excess in case you crash the car.

Comment: Yes it is usual. That's why I'm asking here for the unusual solution.

Comment: Debit card? You'd need to have enough money in your account for it to work though. Otherwise, just get a credit card, it'll make your life much much easier for this sort of thing!

Comment: The problem is when you have a rather low income and a unregular income, it isn't so easy to get one in Switzerland.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a solution in between the usual and the unusual would be to use prepaid credit cards. On my last visit to the US (Florida), I saw them being sold in many stores. All major CC seems to offer them (VISA, MC, AMEX). Semantically they are Debit cards, but apparently everybody accepting credit cards, accept these prepaid cards as well.

I haven't seen these cards being sold in shops elsewhere, but there are different companies that offer them on the Internet Google for ["Prepaid Credit card"](http://www.google.be/webhp?aq=0&q=prepaid%20credit%20card#sclient=psy-ab&hl=nl&safe=off&site=webhp&source=hp&q=prepaid%20credit%20card&btnK=Google%20zoeken&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9076463d8f1d7c5a&biw=1332&bih=684) to find one in your area.

See [money.stackexchange.com](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/what-is-a-good-prepaid-credit-card) which might be related

Comment: I also tried it once with a prepaid credit card in Poland. The problem with that is that you cannot refund money (at least they told me so). So you can't get your deposit back.

Comment: These are just called "debit cards" in Australia. A card that allows access to your own money but is not part of the Visa or Mastercard network are called "ATM cards". I think I have heard that some countries use the term "debit card" for what we call "ATM card" so it's all confusing. You can definitely refund money to a Visa/Mastercard debit card in Australia. They are functionally identical to credit cards only without being an instant bank loan.

Comment: @Roflcoptr The correct car rentals should never charge your Credit Card for the caution. They only reserve the right to charge your card later for a given amount. At the final payment this right is returned. I often pay my carrentals with my ATM card or cash, to keep my cc as "full" as possible

Comment: **A tip**: avoid the terms "credit card" and "debit card". Just say "Visa card" or "Mastercard" to prevent the other person from second guessing what you mean.

Comment: Rental places might also take a low-tech "card impression" on the old card-swiping device. They will not process it with the bank but will tear it up when you return the car safely.

Comment: @hippietrail: Almost but worse (in terms of the confusing difference): we have debit cards issued by our banks for direct access to our own money .... and those are on the VISA (or Mastercard) networks :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed. This was worse for international misunderstanding years ago when only a few countries had non-credit Visa and Mastercard. Now more people are aware of it but still have trouble with clear wording.