# Do European car rental agencies accept debit cards instead of credit cards?

Tags: europe, car-rentals, payment-cards

I don't currently have a credit card and would prefer not to get one. Can I use a regular debit card instead to leave a deposit?

This question is focused on Europe and major car rental agencies, but can be answered from the global perspective if there's a universal answer.

Comment: I can add one data point and that is: no. They want a real credit card and alternatively you can leave them with a huge deposit.

Comment: @mts I wonder what's the reasoning behind this. It's not like you can charge unlimited amounts of money on a credit card, they usually have a fixed limit.

Comment: They can lock in a certain amount (and do so AFAIK) but not sure what happens when said amount exceeds your limit.

Comment: Your question has inspired me to ask that one: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67368/would-i-ever-need-credit-card-if-my-debit-card-is-issued-by-master-visa

Comment: Where is your debit card issued? Related [Q for Italy](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/23317/32134) and [older Q for Poland](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2973/32134)

Comment: @mts Czech Republic, MasterCard

Answer (score 4):

Speaking for France, The majority of payment cards that are issued are debit cards.

Car rental agencies would be quickly out of business if they refused them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a question of insurances.
Major credit cards (visa, MC, AMEX) are internationally recognized compared to your local bank debit card.

(after a quick google regarding US rental with a debit card)
When renting with a debit card, most agencies will do a credit check and that might not be possible when renting in Europe (even from a international company like Avis or Hertz)